# Why I don't get the data when going on the route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, server

When I go to route `'/gallery'`, I want to receive data from the file "posts.json".
I get the data from the file using the `fs` module and using the `read()` method for read data from a file "posts.json".

As a result, I get the error: 'ReferenceError: fs is not defined'

**How to implement show data from the file "posts.json" when navigating through the route `'/gallery'` using the `fs` module?**

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const  Database =  require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const  db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    const items = db.read();
    res.send(items);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

**db.js:**

```js
class Database {

    constructor(){
        this.fs = require('fs');
        this.pictures = [];
    }

    read() {
        fs.readFile('./posts.json', (err, data)=> {
            if(err) {
                throw err;
            }else {
               return this.pictures = data;
            }
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

Comment: You wrote fs.readFile instead of THIS.fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forgot to write `this` keyword as you are trying to access `fs` attribute that you initialized in the constructor with `this.fs = require('fs')`.

You used it to access `pictures` attribute, but not `fs`

Answer (score 2):

use:

`this.fs.readFile` in your `read` function, instead of `fs.readFile`. Since you required it in the constructor, and assigned it to `this.fs`;

Or `require` the `fs` module at the beginning of `db.js`

```
const fs = require('fs');
```

And use it without `this`.

Comment: he actually require it to initialize an attribute value. OP forget to use "this" keyword